# Offline Cache Web Application with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, memcached, offline

I have faced some problems with offline web application which used **VueJS(frontend)** and **Django(Backend)** with **postgres database**.
Currently **postgres database** are installed on **cloud** while frontend and backend are on local computer, in order to avoid retrieve or update data every time from cloud, I have used **cache** in **Django** to store data temporary.

But when internet connection is disconnected, cache suddenly stop working and show error on database disconnected.
Are there any solution to add some offline service worker to avoid database connection error and allow cache to work both offline and online ?

Thank you

Comment: the connection to your server is lost so django cant make use of its cache. You want to look into progessive web apps and service workers. You need to add a offline cache and in the browser of your user to store some values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @hansTheFranz but I am not sure about service worker and what I need is offline cache inside Django itself since I want cache to provide some internal function as postgres database. 
As you mentioned, I need to install offline cache but I am not sure how. Could you mention it a little bit more ?